# Using AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests with Oracle Procs which COMMIT

Tags: java, oracle, spring, testing, junit

I'm using **AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests** to run a simple test:

```
public class MyTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    @Test
    public void simpleProcTest()
    {
        simpleJdbcTemplate.update("BEGIN p_dummy_commit; END;");
    }
}
```

The proc mentioned does a simple table update then a COMMIT.

Problem is, the change made by this dummy proc doesn't get rolled back as I'd hoped.

Background: we have a large app which has lots of procs which do this, I am trying to find out how to test these in a rolled-back manner *despite* them containing explicit COMMIT statements.

I'm hoping to take advantage of a transaction-nesting capability, which I'd thought I might be getting for "free" with this Spring superclass. It seems I don't though.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

I've confirmed the rollback succeeds as expected when I do direct SQL UPDATEs outside of a proc, so my Spring datasource and transactionManager look to be behaving OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been advised offline that because our procs are littered with explicit COMMIT statements we just  aren't going to be able to easily perform 100% clean rollbacks.  Bah humbug.

Answer (score 0):

[Nested Transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation-nested) are probably the way to go.

Apparently (according to [`DataSourceTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) nested transactions require the use of the [`SavePoint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Savepoint.html) mechanism. And if I understand the [Oracle Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm) right, you can probably roll back the outer transaction if your stored procedure sets a save point.

But how you can get Spring to know your SavePoint is beyond my grasp. Probably you have to call it explicitly in your SQL.

Comment: I'm starting to think that my app procs' many embedded COMMIT statements are going to make any kind of easy auto-rollback mechanism impossible. As you mention, it does seem like Oracle uses SAVEPOINT for this very purpose but I don't know if replacing all these explicit commits is going to be an option unfortunately.